# Query to find all records in A that has no join records in B for specific criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to construct a query to find all records in a PostgreSQL table (`a`) for which:

- There are no records **at all** in table `b` having `state='ready'`

It doesn't matter the reason for no records in table `b` with the state `state='ready'` (it can be there is no association, the association is null, the state is different or the state is null)

In the below example I expect to find records of ID: `2,3,4` in table `a`.

I have tried with a left join, but I can't make it work.

PS. The query has to be performant, since tables have millions of records.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5thdgDkv5B6Mx56NyHfoiz/0

Comment: You should provide sample data and desired results *in the question*.  External sites can be used to augment a question, but they should not be required to understand one.  How are the tables related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you just want `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1
                  from b
                  where b.? = a.? and  -- whatever the join conditions are
                        b.state = 'ready'
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE id NOT IN 
(SELECT b.a_id FROM b WHERE b.state = 'ready');
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5thdgDkv5B6Mx56NyHfoiz/2